# which smart html editor can work with jsf 1.2?

Tags: java, jsf, editor, ckeditor, jsf-1.2

i want to create a module in existing project. In that project requirement is that, a non technical person can enter the data in the web page using smart editors and store that data in the database.

presently my project is developed using JSF 1.2 framework. For the requirement i tried with ckeditor, but it is asking me JSF 2.0.

please guide me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a component library that includes an editor. Since this will take away the component development for you.

As you are using JSF 1.X you need to look for old versions of those component libraries, like

- Richfaces 3.3.X -> http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/editor.jsf;jsessionid=6BF69454022F877FC053F7A5432465CA?c=editor&tab=usage
- Primefaces 1.1, does not have a live demo online anymore, but does have an editor -> http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/downloads/detail?name=primefaces-1.1.zip